# How to add a calculated field to a drill report in SQL Server reporting services 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008

Hi created my first report using SQL Server reporting services 2008...

It summarizes call results numbers for a call center.
It displays 3 columns: General Result, Detailed Result and Qty of Calls.
It summarized at the General Result level, and then you can drill down in each value of General Result, to a Detailed Result Level.
For example, a General Result value is "Technical Question" and a few Detailed Results for that is "Windows", "MAC", "Printer", etc.
So each row in the table (actually a view) would be like this:
"Technical Question", "Windows", 5
"Technical Question", "MAC", 3
"Technical Question","Printer",4
"Customer Service","Shipping",6
"Customer Service","Billing",2
etc

I want to add a column to the right with percentages.
And also a row at the bottom with totals.

Ideas on how to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the report items collection in your expression.